# Convert String into dateTime

Tags: java, date

I have to strings like this

```
Thu Oct 03 07:47:22 2013
Mon Jul 05 08:47:22 2013
```

I want to compare these dates, I am using  `SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyy")` but it gives me an exception : `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:`

Please help me to solve this problem!

Comment: Give us the code...How are you comparing the dates?

Comment: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy` one extra y, is that the issue?

Comment: That pattern is fine. Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `y` for year:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy
```

but you should use a more robust library, `org.jodatime`.

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH::mm:ss yyyy");
DateTime time = format.parseDateTime("Thu Oct 03 07:47:22 2013");
```

Comment: did you try with yyy?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `y` in the format. 4 `y` were required for the year(though it may work fine with `yyy`, its better to use `yyyy` as it'll make your format more readable to others). And to get the `DateTime` object, you can use the `Date` object which you get by parsing the String to construct your `DateTime`.

Try something like this:-

```
String str = "Thu Oct 03 07:47:22 2013";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"); // You missed a y here.
try {
    Date d = sdf.parse(str);
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(d.getTime()); // Your DateTime Object.
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Parse Exception
}
```

Comment: did you try with yyy?

Comment: @RohitJain,Renjith- Well, it may work with `yyy` also, but `yyyy` will certainly improve the readability.

Comment: @R.J ... Certainly it improves the readability.But yyy does not give any exception.So your answer must be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: It answers the question title of converting a string to datetime. Why should it be a comment?!

Answer (score 0):

try with this method

```
public static Date formatStringToDate(String strDate) throws ModuleException {
    Date dtReturn = null;
    if (strDate != null && !strDate.equals("")) {
        int date = Integer.parseInt(strDate.substring(0, 2));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(strDate.substring(3, 5));
        int year = Integer.parseInt(strDate.substring(6, 10));

        Calendar validDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, date);
        dtReturn = new Date(validDate.getTime().getTime());
    }
    return dtReturn;
}
```